# how to get the whole tweet instead of a part of tweet with links

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

I am using Twython library for tweets acquisition. but most of the tweets are not complete and end with a short URL where the whole tweet is present. Is there any way that I can get through it.
here is the sample code:

```
results=twitter.search(q="python")
all_tweets=results['statuses']
for tweet in all_tweets:
    print(tweet['text'])
```

[image: Click here to see the output]

Comment: Please, show the code you are using and provide some more details (outputs, expected return, etc). Well-documented questions are easier to be answered.

Comment: I have shown the code

Comment: u can see the output as well :)

Comment: @ZerryMirza is my solution working for you?

Comment: @SamHecquet yes it is working. but unfortunately I m having another problem :(

Comment: @ZerryMirza you should close this one and create a new one

Answer (score 4):

In order to see the extended tweet you just need to supply this parameter to your search query: `tweet_mode=extended`.

Then, you will find the extended tweet in the `full_text` field of the returned tweet. I don't work in Python, but based on the documentation I think you should do something like:

```
results = twitter.search(q='pizza', tweet_mode='extended')
for result in results['statuses']:
    print(result['full_text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching only the Tweet text (content of the tweet itself), if you look at `results['statuses']` object you'll see all tweets you've fetched, and if you print your tweet object, you'll get all the metadata relate to it.
I wrote a blog post on how to use Twython with Twitter search API, https://pythonstack.org/2017/12/collecting-data-from-twitter-rest-search-api-using-python/
I hope you find it helpful.