# tweet_search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tweet_mode'

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy, tweets

I am using Tweepy library for tweets acquisition. But most of the tweets are not complete and end with a link where the whole tweet is present. I'm using `tweet_mode="extended"` but its giving an error message.

Here is the code:

```
tweets, max_id = tweet_search(api, search_phrase, max_tweets,
max_id=max_id, since_id=since_id,
tweet_mode="extended", geocode=USA)
```

Comment: What's the error, you should write that down too

Comment: I have written the error in the title of question.
It is : 
tweet_search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tweet_mode'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the whole tweet instead of a part of tweet with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697667/how-to-get-the-whole-tweet-instead-of-a-part-of-tweet-with-links)